# News Service in PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, rss, feed

What would be the best way of allowing a news service to be used by many external websites? I want to allow external websites to use some of my functions to display news. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up RSS feeds for each item you wanted to let people use. Not sure what sort of system you're running, but WordPress allows you to make custom RSS feeds based on almost anything you want; custom post types, categories, etc.

Comment: IMHO, You should write some simple api, allowing foreign sites to get the data in a specific format, lets say XML or JSON

Answer (score 0):

If your news articles are stored in a database table then you can easily extract them using php and populate an rss feed with them.

Then all you do is provide the link to those you wish to use it.

The benefit being it should be straight-forward for them to extract the information they need from it aswell.

An example of how to do this is: http://www.carronmedia.com/create-an-rss-feed-with-php/